# Convert string base64 to Object JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data

I need to save a JS file in the database and then retrieve this file.

When saving the file and converting to string base64, how do I read this base64 file and convert it back to the original format (JS file)?

I'm saving to the database with axios like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
const create = (formData, onUploadProgress) => {
  return http.post(
    '/api/v1/maps/upload',
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      onUploadProgress,
    }
  );
};
```

**Original file:**

```
export default {
label: "Test file JS",
  viewBox: "0 0 800 1120",
  locations: [
    {
      id: "01",
      path:
        "M 445.73 747.67 205.6 533.44 574.22 1 797.73 195.63 799 204.74 535.49 492.74 591.82 587.22 445.73 747.67 Z"
    },
    {
      id: "02",
      path: "M 1 818.38 203.08 530.9 443.39 749.75 105.29 1119.38 1 818.38 Z"
    }
  ]
};
```

File retrieved from base64 database:

```
ZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQgewpsYWJlbDogIlRlc3QgZmlsZSBKUyIsCiAgdmlld0JveDogIjAgMCA4MDAgMTEyMCIsCiAgbG9jYXRpb25zOiBbCiAgICB7CiAgICAgIGlkOiAiMDEiLAogICAgICBwYXRoOgogICAgICAgICJNIDQ0NS43MyA3NDcuNjcgMjA1LjYgNTMzLjQ0IDU3NC4yMiAxIDc5Ny43MyAxOTUuNjMgNzk5IDIwNC43NCA1MzUuNDkgNDkyLjc0IDU5MS44MiA1ODcuMjIgNDQ1LjczIDc0Ny42NyBaIgogICAgfSwKICAgIHsKICAgICAgaWQ6ICIwMiIsCiAgICAgIHBhdGg6ICJNIDEgODE4LjM4IDIwMy4wOCA1MzAuOSA0NDMuMzkgNzQ5Ljc1IDEwNS4yOSAxMTE5LjM4IDEgODE4LjM4IFoiCiAgICB9CiAgXQp9Ow==
```

[Converter here!](https://www.utilities-online.info/base64)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to decode base64 to string you'll need to use [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob).

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script id="output" type="module"></script>
  <script type="module">
    const content = atob("ZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQgewpsYWJlbDogIlRlc3QgZmlsZSBKUyIsCiAgdmlld0JveDogIjAgMCA4MDAgMTEyMCIsCiAgbG9jYXRpb25zOiBbCiAgICB7CiAgICAgIGlkOiAiMDEiLAogICAgICBwYXRoOgogICAgICAgICJNIDQ0NS43MyA3NDcuNjcgMjA1LjYgNTMzLjQ0IDU3NC4yMiAxIDc5Ny43MyAxOTUuNjMgNzk5IDIwNC43NCA1MzUuNDkgNDkyLjc0IDU5MS44MiA1ODcuMjIgNDQ1LjczIDc0Ny42NyBaIgogICAgfSwKICAgIHsKICAgICAgaWQ6ICIwMiIsCiAgICAgIHBhdGg6ICJNIDEgODE4LjM4IDIwMy4wOCA1MzAuOSA0NDMuMzkgNzQ5Ljc1IDEwNS4yOSAxMTE5LjM4IDEgODE4LjM4IFoiCiAgICB9CiAgXQp9Ow==");
    
    console.log(content);
    const body = document.body;
    const script = document.getElementById("output");
    script.text = content;
    script.src = "content.js";
    
    //import * as example from "./content.js";
    //console.log(example.locations);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but atob doesn't work, as you can see in the Sandbox ( https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-surf-unoef?file=/src/App.js ), I need to convert it back to an object and the atob convert to text

Comment: @CleitondeFreitas Added an adjustment. The content is now appended back to an existing script tag.